# Can you use Google Analytics in an asynchronous way on a mobile Application? Android and iOS SDK

Tags: android, ios, sdk, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

there is a User Based Insurance app (for iOS and Android) that we want to track using Google Analytics. This app will only send data when the user is connected to wi-fi in order to save consumption on their data plan. The question is: 
Will Google Analytics tracking work in an asynchronous way (will data send to Google Analytics Servers even when the app data is not sent at the same time?)
I found some references to customize the GA data dispatch settings for [Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch), but I'm not sure if the fact that user behavior data will be sent only when connected to wi-fi will have any implication.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.